# Full backup of Moto X

Tags: backup

I have a non rooted Moto X (2014), which does not have a SD slot. I am looking for a full backup method which either is over the net or preferably uses an OTG cable to a flash drive.

Helium apparently does not work with Moto X phones.  In this instance I cannot use adb.

A full backup is desired.

Are there any other options?

Comment: Mistyped? There's no Moto C in 2014.

Comment: You are correct, and I have corrected the typo.

Comment: Is the bootloader still locked?

Comment: The bootloader says locked, but I believe that the phone should be an unlocked phone.

Answer (score 1):

I've heard of [this tool](https://drfone.wondershare.com/android-data-backup-and-restore.html). It doesn't seem to be complicated to use.

Also, I've heard of [this one that requires rooting the phone](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/full-android-backup/).

Just to let you know, I didn't test them, so I can't say if they meet the expectations. I would choose the first one, because it apparently does not require root (and, the second one is not available in my country). However, since you have already rooted your phone, you can try either one (or maybe any other different app).

Comment: To be clear the phone has not been rooted.

Comment: I believe I misread it on the question. I believe the answer is still helpful though.

Comment: I agree, and I am studying the first tool, to see if it will work for me.